# Database for properties of categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, soft-question

Oftentimes, it is useful to know what nice properties a category has and what constructions can be performed there: whether it is additive, abelian or neither, what is its final object (if it has one), how products are constructed (if they exist), and similar things. I am sure that anyone who works frequently with categories has already had the idea of making a list of the most useful and important properties of the most common categories, so as not to have to deduce or search them again and again every time. Unfortunately, it is a time-consuming task, and it is questionable whether the benefits are worth the effort (given that human time is finite). Nevertheless, someone might have dared the step, and, having done the effort, they might be willing to share the result, so as to increase the total benefit of their work for the community. So my question is:

> Is anybody aware of the existence of a database (even if informal/incomplete) with the most important properties of the most common categories (however subjective the terms "most important" and "most common" might be)?

Comment: Someone has at least had the idea before, but it seems it didn't go anywhere: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/database+of+categories

Comment: There are just too many! I personally don’t feel like this is how the information is organized in my head at all - I don’t have a mental database of categories, I have a mental database of classes of constructions of categories, which usually share properties. Similarly classes of constructions of limits / colimits in different kinds of categories.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I didn't have a specific structure in mind, I was just asking for an online location where such data is stored, in whatever form. Classes of constructions (and properties thereof) would certainly be interesting too, and even more efficient than individual cases.